# Is there a difference between the two soda bottles in Bad Piggies?

Tags: bad-piggies

In Bad Piggies there are two different "soda bottles" which propel a craft: one black and one green, as seen here:

[image: Bad Piggies]

What is the difference between the two bottles? Unlike other parts such as engines they both appear to have the same power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

they serve no functional difference (as in one being stronger). It's only purpose is to seperate 'blasts'. You can launch all the blacks, and then launch the greens when you need to, or vice versa.

Comment: The same is true for blue/red rockets. They're only meant to provide players with a way to propell the piggies in separate steps.